# Repeater shows wrong column content

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater to show an order confirmation. It is bound to a table generated with Entity Framework code first. The table contains the right information and the repeater shows all the information right except for the part where I show the totals which I paste below.

I believe that this part also works okay but **quantity** does not. For example if I add 5 products it will only show one, but if I put a break point and I run the code in debug mode I see that the value inserted in the Quantity table is 5 not 1, so the Quantity value on the table is inserted correctly, but the repeater reports 1.

Here is the code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptConfirmOrder" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>


                   <fieldset class = "OrderConfirmationFieldset"><legend class ="OrderDataLegend">Order Summary</legend>

                    <td align="left" width="60%" runat="server" id="Td25">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity: " CssClass = "lblOrderConfirmation">
                        </asp:Label> <%# Eval("Quantity")  %>
                        <br />

                    </td>

                        <td align="left" width="60%" runat="server" id="Td26">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text="Product Name: " CssClass = "lblOrderConfirmation">
                            </asp:Label><%# Eval("ProductName" ,"{0:c}" )  %>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="60%" runat="server" id="Td27">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductPrice" runat="server" Text="Product price: " CssClass = "lblOrderConfirmation">
                            </asp:Label>  <%# Eval("ProductPrice" ,"{0:c}" )  %>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="60%" runat="server" id="Td28">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubtotal" runat="server" Text="Subtotal: " CssClass = "lblOrderConfirmation">
                            </asp:Label>  <%# Eval("Subtotal" ,"{0:c}" )  %>
                            <br />
                        </td>

                        <td align="left" width="60%" runat="server" id="Td29">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Total: " CssClass = "lblOrderConfirmation">
                            </asp:Label>  <%# Eval("Total" ,"{0:c}" )  %>
                            <br />
                        </td>
</ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

Can Anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please make sure Data is not cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repeater markup doesn't look right.
have it as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptConfirmOrder" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptConfirmOrder_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        // stuff
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And if you have it that way, and this was a paste error, then forget the value in the database/entity etc.

You can verify accurately, what value is being bound by tapping into the row data bound event as follows..

```
protected void rptConfirmOrder_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as YOUR_ENTITY_TYPE;
      Debug.Assert(5 == dataItem.Quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! It was indeed a paste error the repeater does contain the <ItemTemplate> tags, I am about to test your suggestion

Comment: the assertion failed, but the logic is right. The problem is the linq to sql statement in which I use Take(1) but it is not getting the last it gets the first record

Comment: glad that you found the root cause. to get the last entry reliably, 'descending sort' the results by date and do FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the < itemtemplate > tags in after the opening repeater and close it off before the closing repeater tag.

Comment: thank you for the answer, my repeater does contain the  </ItemTemplate> tag it was a paste error. What else can it be?